# I want to create a RSS feed on a public website that shows where I am via GPS on a map

Tags: xml, gps, rss

I bought a GPS tracker for my motorcycle.  Family can log into the website and track me with no problem.  I want to create a simple website that can allow friends/fellow riders to see where I am as well.  The GPS tracker lets me log in and grab "XML" code that looks like this:

```html
<rss xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>GoTrack Location Feed for Edsrocket new</title>
<link>http://www.gotrack.com</link>
<description>Location Matters</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<item>
<title>
Location reading on Wed, 22 Apr 2015 17:12:34 -0400
</title>
<description>1324 NW Main St, Lee's Summit MO</description>
<georss:point>38.9372168 -94.3922705</georss:point>
<speed>0</speed>
<direction>0.0</direction>
<pubDate>Wed, 22 Apr 2015 17:12:34 -0400</pubDate>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I then need to either have either complete HTML code or an RSS feed url to add it to the webpage.

I have read about XML, RSS, and watched YouTube videos.. and I just can't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to share the XML using Dropbox:

1. Save the XML to your [Dropbox Public folder](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/16) as a XML-file (for example georssfeed.xml)
2. Share a public link to your friends. The link will something like: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1234567/georssfeed.xml

When you get new GPS data, overwrite the file in your Public folder with a new file or create and "publish" a new RSS feed file the same way as described earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to be RSS, so if it is public, people should be able to simply subscribe to it if you give them the url location of it.